# Laravel. Database seeder multiple rows not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to seed database with multiple rows with a seeder:

```
public function run()   {
    DB::table('users')->insert([

        [
            'name' => 'Guest',
            'surname' => 'Guest',
            'email' => 'guest@domain.com',
            'phone' => '+777',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
            'is_admin' => false,
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Alexander',
            'surname' => 'Jones',
            'email' => 'asd@asd.com',
            'phone' => '+12321321312',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
            'is_admin' => true,
        ]

    ]);
```

However when i run `php artisan db:seed` it seeds only with the first row. How can i make seeder for multiple rows? L5.2 documentation lacks this kind of information. Please help!

Comment: Instead of `use DB`, can you `use App\User` .. and do something like `User::insert()`. Does that work?

Comment: This should work.

Comment: @TheAlpha: you mean my code should work? But in fact, it doesn't... To prateekkathal: it didn't work, same - just 1 row, instead of 2.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: @MikeHarrison I am getting errors there, but not related to a seeder.

Comment: Can you post the most recent error? It could still be related.

Comment: @MikeHarrison `/srv/www/sc/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))` ||| I just wonder, why such a simple task becomes such a hard one in the same time in Laravel..

Comment: That's not the error that's just part of the stacktrace. The error will resemble something starting with: `[2016-12-09 21:29:34] local.ERROR: exception ...` and then the actual error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130433/discussion-between-alexander-kim-and-mike-harrison).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through chat we discovered that the rows were actually being inserted but when calling to the DB through w/e tool the OP was using was only returning 1 result at a time which made it appear.

For other users using Sequel Pro (https://sequelpro.com/) I suggest looking at the table view and not running queries as that may be misleading. Not entirely sure but we think that it is adding a limit of 1 to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this once..

$mul_rows= [
    [ 'name' => 'Guest',
            'surname' => 'Guest',
            'email' => 'guest@domain.com',
            'phone' => '+777',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
            'is_admin' => false,],
    [  'name' => 'Alexander',
            'surname' => 'Jones',
            'email' => 'asd@asd.com',
            'phone' => '+12321321312',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
            'is_admin' => true,]
];

foreach ($mul_rows as $rows) {
   //$insert = DB::table('departments')->insert($mul_rows); old
   $insert= DB::table('users')->insert($rows);
if($insert){
//success message here
}else{
//Failure message here
}
}
```